# Trying to load json through Vue Axios

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to include a local JSON file from the `static` directory called `blogs.json` which has a load of blogs inside it.

I'm currently loading the blogs via Vue Axios which is a module I'm including in Nuxt JS.

Currently, the blogs are being loaded from the json file perfectly fine, however there is a noticeable few ms delay before the blogs are loaded, I'm trying to figure out a better approach to load the json file and populate the `blogs` array listed inside `data()`

This is my current code:

```
<script>
import PageBanner from '~/components/PageBanner';

export default {
  head: {
    title: 'Site Title: Blog',
    meta: [
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Site description' }
    ]
  },
  components: {
    PageBanner
  },
  data () {
    return {
      blogs: [],
      isLoading: true
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.axios.get("/articles/blogs.json").then((response) => {
      this.blogs = response.data
      this.isLoading = false
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

This works just fine, but how could I modify this to load the json more quickly?

Comment: I believe your JSON is local data, then you do not need to use the async code in order to fetch data. you can directly use as the variable if you want it to load more quickly.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with nuxt.js (as i am with vue.js only) but you may take a look at the documentation, especially Middleware here: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware

Comment: How would I implement this?

Comment: How big is your blogs.json file?

Answer (score 5):

Just import it, do this and it should work God willing:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- There should be no delay -->
        {{blogs}} 
    </div>
<template>
<script>
import PageBanner from '~/components/PageBanner';

import blogsFromJson from '~/articles/blogs.json'; // Or wherever it is found

export default {
  head: {
    title: 'Site Title: Blog',
    meta: [
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Site description' }
    ]
  },
  components: {
    PageBanner
  },
  data () {
    return {
      blogs: blogsFromJson, // Just set it here
      isLoading: true
    }
  },
  /* No need for this anymore
  created () {
    this.axios.get("/articles/blogs.json").then((response) => {
      this.blogs = response.data
      this.isLoading = false
    })
  }
  */
}
</script>
```

Comment: @RyanHolton Please mark this answer as correct if it worked for you. Thanks!